# in ggplot2, print an expression in the facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some functions with their gradients using the `ggplot2` package in `r`.

```
p = 3
n0 = 100
z0 = seq(0.01, 0.99, length = n0)
AB0 = matrix(rbeta(600,4,1), nrow = n0)

library(ggplot2)
ab.names=c(paste("g",1:p,sep=""),paste("g' ",1:p,sep=""))
pl0=ggplot(data.frame(ab = c(AB0), ID = rep(ab.names, each = n0), Z = z0),
           aes(x = Z, y = ab)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free",nrow = 2, ncol = p) + theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Unpenalized VCM",expression(nabla~"g  and  "~"g")) + ylab("")
```

I want to switch the rows and add the nabla symbol in the title of the plots in the 1st row before switching them to the second row. To be clear, the 1st row is for the functions, and the 2nd row is for the gradients where the nabla symbol should appear in the title.

Here is a screenshot of the outcome

[image: screenshot of the functions and their gradients]

Comment: you might have to make two plots one for functions and one for gradient and then put the title directly above the gradients and then use cowplot, patchwork or gridextra to stitch them together

Comment: How about you create 2 columns: 1 with either nabla g or g values, the second one with 1:5. Then you assign your values to these 2 columns and you do a multi-panel facet_wrap http://zevross.com/blog/2019/04/02/easy-multi-panel-plots-in-r-using-facet_wrap-and-facet_grid-from-ggplot2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `labeller` argument to `facet_wrap` might come in handy, if you set it to "label_parsed". Example:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(2),
                y = rnorm(2),
                ID = c(paste0('g~', 1:2),
                       paste0('g~nabla~', 1:2)
                       )
                )


d |>
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(. ~ ID, 
               labeller = label_parsed,
               nrow = 2
               )
```

[image: parse strip label expressions]